# Why is HttpWebResponse losing data?

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebresponse

In another question, people are getting incomplete data when reading from a HttpWebResponse via GetResponseStream().

I too encountered this problem when reading data from an embedded device which should send me the configuration of 1000 inputs, all in all 32 bytes header and 64 bytes * 1000 resulting in 64032 bytes of data.

Reading the response stream directly only gives me data for the first 61 and a half inputs, from there on only zeros.

**Version a) Not working:**

```
int headerSize = 32;
int inputSize = 64;
byte[] buffer = new byte[(inputSize*1000) + headerSize];

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}

response.Close();
return buffer;
```

To visualize the problem, I printed the 64 bytes for each input configuration seperately. It consists basically of 40 ascii chars and a few bytes which represent boolean and integer values.

Version A) Output:

```
1/1000 | 46656E7374657220576F686E656E2020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020000000000F0EB0AA00008100000001800000100090010020
2/1000 | 42574D20576F686E656E202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020000000000F0EB0AA00008100000001800000100091010080
…
61/1000 | 53656E736F72203631202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000000000000000000010003300000000001000C3010000
62/1000 | 53656E736F7220363220202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
63/1000 | 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
…
999/1000 | 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000/1000 | 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

When I copy the ResponseStream to a new MemoryStream, I can read all 1000 inputs completely without any corrupt bytes.

**Version B) Working perfectly:**

(See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22354617/6290907 which fixed my problem in the first case)

```
int headerSize = 32;
int inputSize = 64;
byte[] buffer = new byte[(inputSize*1000) + headerSize];

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(memStream);
        memStream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        memStream.Close();
    }
}

response.Close();
return buffer;
```

Version B) Output

```
1/1000 | 46656E7374657220576F686E656E2020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020000000000F0EB0AA00008100000001800000100090010020
2/1000 | 42574D20576F686E656E202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020000000000F0EB0AA00008100000001800000100091010080
…
61/1000 | 53656E736F72203631202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000000000000000000010003300000000001000C3010000
62/1000 | 53656E736F72203632202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000000000000000000010003300000000001000C3010000
63/1000 | 53656E736F72203633202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200000000000000000000010003300000000001000C3010000
…
999/1000 | 53656E736F7220393939202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020000000000000000000001000DA030000000010006A050000
1000/1000 | 53656E736F7220313030302020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020000000000000000000001000DB030000000010006B050000
```

From a technical point of view: **Why is the HttpWebResponse losing data when accessed directly?**
I don't just want it to work, but I want to understand why version a fails and version b is successfull while both depend on the same source of data (response.GetResponseStream()).
What is happening under the hood in this case?

Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `int` returned by `Stream.Read`, as described by the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes
>   are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has
>   been reached.

I'm willing to bet that only part of the stream is returned in the first call.

If you called `Stream.Read` repeatedly, you'd get all the bytes in the end. The http stream is simply loading more slowly than your code is running - it doesn't have time to complete before you call `Read`.

By using `CopyTo` with a `MemoryStream`, the call blocks until the whole stream is read. Wrapping in a `StreamReader`, then calling `ReadToEnd` would get the same successful result.

Comment: int bytesRead = 0;
int bytesToRead = buffer.Length;
do
{
    int n = s.Read(buffer, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
    bytesRead += n;
    bytesToRead -= n;
} while (bytesToRead != 0);

Comment: That did the trick! I am pretty new to the embedded world and was working with text only before, so I missed compensation the number of bytes read when not using a text based StreamReader.
Thank you so much!